# Dynamic SQL request in a PHP code

Tags: php, sql, web

I'm currently coding a plugin in PHP and I have a list box containing numbers from 1 to 30 and a "submit" button. The plugin page is running some SQL request.

The point is the SQL request should update when you choose a number in the `list box` and click the submit button.

For instance:

```
SELECT G.xxx 
FROM yyy M, 
     zzz G 
WHERE M.name = G.nomfield 
AND G.nomfield = "xxx" 
AND G.idfield = 01 
AND G.xxx = $numberfrom1to30
```

the display should be different according to the number selected in the `list box` after the submit button is clicked. How should I do this?

I tried to:

```
<?php 
$selected = isset( $_GET['numberfrom1to30'] ) ? $_GET['numberfrom1to30'] : "" ;
$selectedValue = 'selected="selected"';
?>
```

```
<?php           
$numberfrom1to30= $_GET['numberfrom1to30'];
?>
```

But here's my error: `Unknown column '$numberfrom1to30' in 'where clause'`

Comment: `AND G.nomfield = "xxx" AND G.idfield = "01" AND G.xxx = "$numberfrom1to30"`.. Missed the quotes

Comment: obligatory: you are open to injection.

  ok, on topic, you are not escaping the string if the variable name is being returned to you in the error.

Comment: Filter variable - http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php  or use a regex or cast the variable to an int.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues: SQL injection, and using the wrong quotes in the query:

```
//convert to number to prevent SQL injection
$numberfrom1to30 = intval($_GET['numberfrom1to30']);

$query = "SELECT G.xxx FROM yyy M, zzz G WHERE M.name = G.nomfield AND G.nomfield = 'xxx' AND G.idfield = 01 AND G.xxx = $numberfrom1to30";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it definitely works !!